# Name followed by :: must be a class or namespace name

Tags: c++, function, class

I have reviewed numerous articles on this subject both here and elsewhere on the internet and have developed my code to conform with what I've learned. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to solve this problem. Here are the pieces of the puzzle:

The defined class:

```
class FileData {
private:
    char* filename;

public:
    FileData();
    void CloseFile(std::fstream file);
    int DeleteFile(char* fname);
    int FileExist(char* fname);
    int OpenDestFile(std::fstream file, char* fname);
    int OpenListFile(std::fstream file, char* fname);
    int OpenSourceFile(std::fstream file, char* fname);
    int ReadBuffer(std::fstream file, char* Buffer);
    int ReadListFile(std::fstream file);
    int WipeFile(char* fname);
    int WriteBuffer(std::fstream file, char* Buffer);
};
```

The constructor code:

```
FileData::FileData() : filename(nullptr) {}
```

The defined function that I'm having an issue with (does not matter which function of the class...they all have the same error):

```
int FileData::OpenListFile(std::fstream file, char* fname) {
    int ccode;

    ccode = 0;
    file.open(fname, std::fstream::in);
    if (file.bad()) {
        ccode = -1;
    }
    return ccode;
}
```

As a global variable I declare FileRec as an class of FileData:

```
FileData FileRec;
```

Here is the actual function call that generates the error:

```
if ((ccode = FileRec::OpenListFile(&ListFile, fspec3)) != 0) {
   // ....
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `OpenListFile` does not take a pointer as a first argument. There should be *several* errors here.

Comment: Unless these are `static` methods then calling them as `X::Y()` makes no sense. You call it on an instance `x` like `x.Y()` or `x->Y()` if you have a pointer.

Comment: Note: In C++ it's often a good idea to use `std::string` and a bad idea to use `char*` to retain data. Memory management isn't easy, or even fun. Unless you `strdup()` your arguments you can't be assured you can retain them, and if you do copy, you *must* release in your destructor, which isn't shown, so that could be a leak.

Comment: Tip: Try and pick a naming convention for your function and variable names. You're using both `Buffer` (capitalized) and `fname` (lower-case) indifferently. In a lot of C++ code bases `CapitalStyle` is reserved for classes, where everything else is `lower_case` style.

Comment: Ok. I added "static" to each function definition (except the constructor) in the class and I have the same result? Yes I fixed the "&ListFile" issue in the function call too (simple typo). As for naming conventions used, this is an OLD "C" program that I'm in the process of converting to C++ (and learning at the same time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `OpenListFile()` as an *instance* method, not as a *static* method.  `FileRec` is an `instance` of the `FileData` class.  You need to use the `.` operator to access members of an object instance, eg:

```cpp
FileData FileRec;
std::fstream ListFile;
...
if ((ccode = FileRec.OpenListFile(ListFile, fspec3)) != 0) {
   // ...
}
```

Otherwise, use `static` for any methods that don't need to access any data members of the `FileData` class, and then use the *class name* instead of the *instance name* when using `::`, eg:

```cpp
class FileData {
public:
    static void CloseFile(std::fstream file);
    static int DeleteFile(char* fname);
    static int FileExist(char* fname);
    static int OpenDestFile(std::fstream file, char* fname);
    static int OpenListFile(std::fstream file, char* fname);
    static int OpenSourceFile(std::fstream file, char* fname);
    static int ReadBuffer(std::fstream file, char* Buffer);
    static int ReadListFile(std::fstream file);
    static int WipeFile(char* fname);
    static int WriteBuffer(std::fstream file, char* Buffer);
};

...

int FileData::OpenListFile(std::fstream file, char* fname) {
    file.open(fname, std::fstream::in);
    return file.bad() ? -1 : 0;
}

...

std::fstream ListFile;
if ((ccode = FileData::OpenListFile(ListFile, fspec3)) != 0) {
   // ....
}
```

---

That said, note that you can't pass around a `std::fstream` **by value**, as `std::fstream` is not copyable.  You need to pass it **by reference** or **by pointer** instead:

```cpp
...
int OpenListFile(std::fstream& file, char* fname);
...
```

```cpp
...
int OpenListFile(std::fstream* file, char* fname);
...
```

Comment: It's worth noting having a "class" you never instantiate that's just chock full of `static` methods is really not a class at all.

Comment: @tadman sure, they could be changed into a bunch of free-standing functions in a `namespace` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I appreciate the accurate reply. Earlier today I found the answer about passing the fstream by reference or pointer. Having cut my teeth on C years ago, I'm certainly playing catch up learning C++ after years away from programming, its a monster difference in how things work. Thanks.